# Hi i want to execute a .exe file in between one of my automation test in protractor

Tags: protractor

I am using protractor for non-angular page. In between I have to execute a .exe file to change the system date . But i don't know how to call the .exe file using protractor . I am beginner to protractor . Can some one help me with this question .
Thanks in advance .

Comment: I created an .exe file to change system date using auot it .I can run the exe file manually by double clicking on it but when I execute the same .exe file from protractor code then I am receiving the error :{ Error: spawn filepath EACCES
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:240:19)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:415:16)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
  errno: 'EACCES',
  code: 'EACCES',
  syscall:   'spawn filepath',
  path:   'filepath',
  spawnargs: [],  cmd:   'filePath' }executed
.

Comment: executeFile(exePath) {
        const exec = require('child_process').execFile;
        const child = exec(exePath,function(err,data ) {
            if(err) {
                console.log(err);
            }
            console.log('executed');
            
            process.on('exit',function(){
                child.kill();

            })
        })

Answer (score 0):

If you are using TypeScript, you can change date and time using below code. There is no need to use .exe file

```
let date: Date = new Date();  

date.setDate(18);  

date.setMonth(11);  

date.setFullYear(2000);  

date.setHours(20);  

date.setMinutes(01);  

date.setSeconds(01);  

console.log("Year = " + date.getFullYear());  

console.log("Date = " + date.getDate());  

console.log("Month = " + date.getMonth());  

console.log("Day = " + date.getDay());  

console.log("Hours = " + date.getHours());  

console.log("Minutes = " + date.getMinutes());  

console.log("Seconds = " + date.getSeconds());
```

Similar way you can do in JavaScript also.

Comment: The above comment is not working . The system date needs to be changed .

Comment: The system date needs to be changed .Yes I am using typescript . My test reads the system date which need to be checked after each system date change .Eg: perform a test on 10/10/2010 and perform the same test on 10/10/2017 to see the expiry field is triggered or not .